# Element type is invalid: expected a string in React - Redux

Tags: react-redux

I just started with this React + Redux and I was configuring everything given a tutorial in which they use Axios but I am implementing it with fetch which I do not think is the error that causes me that I hope I am still new and for the same reason I come to ask you.

The complete error that I get is the following.

"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Next I will leave you what I am using as well as its dependencies since sometimes it may be that the dependencies are the cause.

**DEPENDENCIES**
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-devtools": "^3.7.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"

My store:

```
import {createStore,combineReducers,compose,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import pokeReducer from './pokeDucks'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
pokemones: pokeReducer})
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
export default function generateStore() {
const store  =  createStore( rootReducer, composeEnhancers( applyMiddleware( thunk )));
return store;}
```

//constant

```
const dataInicial = {
    array:[]
}
```

//types

```
const OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO = 'OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO';
```

//reducer

```
export default function pokeReducer(state = dataInicial,action){
switch(action.type){
    case OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO:
        return {...state,array:action.payload};
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

//Actions

```
export const obtenerPokemonesAccion = () => async (dispatch,getState) => {
try{

    const response  = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    console.log((await response).json())
    //.then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
    dispatch({
        type:OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO,
        payload:response
    })
}catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
}
```

Comment: you forgot to export something. may be constants and types?

Comment: No, I have everything exported, only that I just realized something, is there a difference between App.js with App.jsx?

Comment: Depends how your compiler is configured. No real difference tho

Comment: I just made some changes and now I get this error: "TypeError: _redux_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4 __. Default.generateStore is not a function"

Comment: Show the file where `generateStore` is used. you probably imported it like so `import { generateStore }`